# Binding multiple events (resize and load) to addEventListener (JQuery)

Tags: javascript

Was googling around, but could not find a proper answer to my question. There are some solutions online that would be helpful only the thing is that I need to change my entire code structure and that is not what I want precisely.

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event) {
    if(window.matchMedia("(min-width: 767px)").matches){
       Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent")).forEach(function(element, index) {
       element.addEventListener("mouseleave", function(event) {
        event.target.style.display = "none";
       });
       document.getElementById("categories-list-box").addEventListener("mouseleave", function(event) {
       if (event.relatedTarget.className.indexOf("tabcontent") == -1) {
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) { 
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
       }
       })
       });
     }
})
```

Comment: Are you asking how to bind the same function to multiple events?

Comment: Code snippet is pointless, when your code is invalid

Comment: Also, please fix your indentation

Answer (score 0):

```
function addListenerMulti(el, s, fn) {
  s.split().forEach(e => el.addEventListener(e, fn, false));
}
```

and usage:

```
addListenerMulti(window, 'mousemove touchmove', function(){…});
```

Answer (score 0):

put your code inside a function, and call it with addEventListener

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', myFunction);
window.addEventListener('resize', myFunction);


function myFunction(){
    if(window.matchMedia("(min-width: 767px)").matches){
        Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent")).forEach(function(element, index) {
            element.addEventListener("mouseleave", function(event) {
                event.target.style.display = "none";
            });
            document.getElementById("categories-list-box").addEventListener("mouseleave", function(event) {
                if (event.relatedTarget.className.indexOf("tabcontent") == -1) {
                    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
                for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) { 
                    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
                }
              }
            })
        });
    }
}
```